# Prove this logical equivalence.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm determining whether this logical proposition is a tautology or a contradiction. I'm stuck in the middle of this equation, and cannot move further using only logical equivalences. The proposition is:

```
 -(-p -> -(-x v -y)) -> -(x ^ y))
```

Can someone brief me on the laws/steps it takes to solve this proposition?

What I have so far:

```
 (-p -> -(-x v -y)) v -(x ^ y)   implication and double negation
 (-p -> (x ^ y)) v (-x v -y)     demorgans twice
 (-p -> x) ^ (-p -> y) v (-x v -y) implication
 p v(x ^ y) v (-x v -y)          distributive
```

Stuck.

Comment: Forget the $p$ and prove $(x \land y) \lor \lnot x \lor \lnot y$.

Comment: First time on a math forum. Is there somewhere where I can read on the meaning of the notations $, \lor, \lnot x, and $p$. Not quite sure what they mean.

Comment: I've used the standard notation for the same symbols you use: $\lnot$ (means not) is your -; $\land$ (means and) is your ^; $\lor$ (means or) is your v. I'm guessing $p$ is just a variable, just like $x$ and $y$; since it's your problem, you're the only one who can enlighten us on that.

Comment: @GivenPie You can also *upvote* helpful answers, as many as you'd like to, as well as accept one. You have ample points now so you've earned the privilege to upvote questions and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start off where you left off. I'll simply carry the disjunct $p$ along for the ride: we'll see in the end that the proposition is a tautology regardless of whether $p$ is true or false.

You've gotten to $(1)$

$$\begin{align} p \lor (x \land y) \lor (\lnot x \lor \lnot y) & \equiv p\lor [(x \land y) \lor \lnot x \lor \lnot y] \tag{1}\\ \\
& \equiv p \lor [(x\lor \lnot x \lor \lnot y) \land (y \lor \lnot x \lor  \lnot y)]\tag{2} \\ \\
& \equiv  p \lor \{[(x \lor \lnot x) \lor \lnot y] \land [(y \lor \lnot y) \lor \lnot x]\}\tag{3}\\ \\
& \equiv p \lor [(T \lor \lnot y) \land (T \lor \lnot x)] \tag{4}\\ \\
& \equiv p \lor (T \land T) \tag{5}\\ \\ 
& \equiv p \lor T \tag{6}\\ \\
& \equiv T\tag{7}\end{align}$$

Thus we have a tautology: It is true regardless of  truth-values of $p, \, x\, \text{ or}\; y$.

$(1)$ just follows by associativity of $\lor$. Note we distribute to get $(2)$, use associativity and commutativity of $\lor$ in $(3)$.
We also make use of the law of the excluded middle: $q \lor \lnot q\equiv T$ in $(4)$. In $(5), (7)$, $T \lor q\equiv T$ (domination) and in $(6)$, $T \land T$ always evaluates to true, by the definition of $\land$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out the rules you applied here goes from the first step: commutative, then distributive, then associativity?, then negation law, then "(T∧T)" is that idempotent, and last rule applied to reach T should be Domination rule. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, correct, save for the first rule uses associativity, and the third is commutativity. But all the rest are right on.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula (there were parentheses that weren't matching, I'm guessing by your derivations)

```
 -(-p -> -(-x v -y)) -> -(x ^ y)
```

or in usual notation

$$\neg(\neg p \to \neg(\neg x \lor \neg y)) \to \neg(x \land y)$$

could be transformed into contrapositive

$$(x \land y) \to (\neg p \to \neg(\neg x \lor \neg y))$$

further using De Morgan's laws to

$$(x \land y) \to (\neg p \to (x \land y))$$

and finally substituting $\alpha = x \land y$ we arrive at

$$\alpha \to (\neg p \to \alpha).$$

This could be seen as tautology by itself, but if you require further reduction, we could uncurry it

$$(\alpha \land \neg p) \to \alpha$$

and weaken the premise to get the identity axiom

$$\alpha \to \alpha.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$